# PHP get a image file and return it in another size

Tags: php, image

I have a bunch if images on my server and i want people to be able to access it with one URL. So i put a list of the URLs in my data base with their id. I need help with just returning the image through PHP.

All the images are square and are between 300x300 and 500x500 but i want them returned as 1000x1000

Here is the code i have i just dont know how to set it to be 1000x1000

```
<?php
 $name = 'test.jpg';
 $fp = fopen($name, 'rb');
 header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
 fpassthru($fp);
?>
```

To be clear. I am not looking to save the images on my server.  I have a image URL from another web site. I want to display on my web site resized, but i want the URL in the img src to have the image as though it was on my server.

Comment: You need to use GD...

Answer (score 0):

Check if your PHP installation supports [GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) by using [`phpinfo()`](https://php.net/phpinfo). In your code, you need to include this:

```
$size = GetimageSize($name);
$image = ImageCreateFromJPEG($name);
$images = ImageCreateTrueColor(1000, 1000);
ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1001, 1001, ImagesX($image), ImagesY($image));
ImageJPEG($images);
```